# Ajax response not coming through from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

My Ajax request is not receiving proper response! It always enters readyState '4' with response status '0' ??

Client Code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                        document.getElementById("lastNameLabel").innerHTML = "response recieved!"; 
                        const responseJSON = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                        if(responseJSON.emailTaken == "false"){
                            window.location = server+"/client/home.html";
                        }
                    }
                };
xhttp.open("POST", server+"/signUp", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("email="+email);
```

server Code (Node.js + Express):

```
app.post('/signUp', (req, res) => {
    res.end("it worked!!");
});
```

I Know my Server is processing the request since I see the url call, but the response never reaches the html client!!. I'm Super Stuck!

Comment: is it a cross origin request - check the browser developer tools console to see if you have any errors regarding cors

Comment: What does that mean??

Comment: it means check the browser **developers** tools console for errors

Comment: Didnt know that existed!! I See this: MLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/signUp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. Fixed The problem!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: there you go, it's a cross origin resource sharing error - you'll need to add CORS handling to your server that you are sending the request to - there's a CORS library for express you can simply plug in to your code so that you don't have to think about it too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting @jaromanda-x's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611675/ajax-response-not-coming-through-from-node-js#comment76210009_44611675) as an answer, you need to enable CORS in your server.

This is how it's done:

```
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

For more info, refer [this express doc](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests) about it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to have your NodeJS server reply with an HTTP response message that includes a status code and reason phrase such as

```
res.status(200).send({ status: 'ok' });
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the problem and `200` is already the default status code so no need to add it either.